# Cannot send POST data by JQuery to controler MVC writted in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, http-post, url-routing

I would like to send data by POST method , which will be send by $.ajax metod on JQuery from formulage. I am trying to send this data to controler writted in PHP. I dont know much about MVC but I have read that controller is responsible for collecting data from user for example by completing formulage.

Here is the code :

```
    `$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://www.somepage.pl/index.php?strona=uzytkownicy',
          data: {                 
             login: hLogin_u,
             nazwaOddzialu: hNazwaOddzialu,
             haslo: hPassword,
             nazwa: hNazwa_u,
             tylkozip: hTylkoIP,
             uprawnienia: myDataCheck
          },
          timeout: 5000,
          cache: false,
          success: function(msg){
             alert('Zapytanie zakonczylo sie sukcesem! Zwrócone dane to '+msg);
          },
          beforeSend: function() {

              $('#errorDiv').show();

              //alert('zaraz wysle sie ajax');     
          },
          error: function(){
             $('#errorDiv').html('<p>Przepraszamy wystąpił błąd!</p>').show();     

             //alert('error nastapil');              
          }
      });
```

I know that only wrong is URL address but I don't know how to send this data to controller. How is correct url.

For example controller name is controler.php and is in directory /contr/controler.php

How is correct url for this configuration.

Am I doing something incorrect sending this data to controller?

I am giving you the code of controller : Maybe this will help to solve the problem.

```
     class Controller // kontroler
    {
     // składowe
     private $strona;
     private $model;
     private $widok;

     // konstruktor
     public function __construct()
     {
     $this->loadModel();
     $this->takeData();
     $this->loadView();
     $this->runView();
     }
     // załadowanie odpowiedniego modelu
     private function loadModel()
     {
    if (Autoryzacja::czyZalogowany() == false)
    {
        $this->strona = "logowanie";
    }
    else
    {
        if (!isset($_GET['strona']))
        {
            $this->strona = "glowna";
        }
        else
        {
                        $this->strona = Narzedzia::security_get($_GET[strona]);
                        global $baza;
                        $baza->execute("SELECT 1 FROM wiadomosci WHERE    
      wiadomosci.pracownik in (1,8) AND
                        NOT EXISTS
                            (SELECT 1 FROM wiadomosci_przeczytania WHERE 
      wiadomosc=id_wiadomosci AND
                            pracownik=$_SESSION[zalogowany_id_c9])");
                        if ($baza->count() > 0)
                        {
                            $this->strona = "glowna";
                        }                                
           }

        }

     $dane=array("logowanie","glowna","dodajw","kalkulator","hasla","zarzadzaj","edycja","chat","  skan", 
     "logi","ajax_logi","kalendarz","ajaxkalendarz","uzytkownicy");
     if (!in_array($this->strona,$dane))
     {
      $this->strona = "glowna";
     }
       $this->model = new $this->strona();
     }
     // załadowanie danych przez model
     private function takeData()
     {
      $this->model->loadData();
     }
     // załadowanie odpowiedniego widoku
     private function loadView()
     {
       $w = $this->strona."_widok";
        $this->widok = new $w($this->model);
     }
     // uruchomienie widoku
     private function runView()
     {
     $this->widok->show();    
     }

   }`
```

Comment: whats the controller name and action name?

Comment: Your are sending the data to index.php not your controler.php file. You either need to send it to the right place or you need to use some type of rewrite to route it correctly.

Comment: Controller is responsible for changing model layer's state.

Comment: So how to send this data to controller. What url would you use in $.ajax() method?